# Prevent an HTTP Response Splitting attack in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, spring-rest, checkmarx

I am using spring controller where I have method get to download file.

controller method is used to download file and I am setting file name as this..

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportname+ ".csv");
```

where filename comes from contrller method, method looks like..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{reportname}")
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable(name="reportname",required=true) @NotBlank String reportname)
            throws IOException {
```

what I am getting in checkmarx is this. reportname param
. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in an HTTP response header in downloadCSV
  This may enable an HTTP Response Splitting attack, in certain older versions that do not mitigate this attack.

Comment: Looks like bad design to allow the caller to decide the filename.

Comment: "without being properly sanitized or validated" - when why don't you change that? What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should unsure(at least) that :

- reportname is not containing a / or .. character
- reportname is not containing any CRLF character
- reportname is as a real filename (perhaps does not contains a . in it) refer to your OS implementation of a filename to add a whitelisting expression .

See [Input Validation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html) from OWASP for more information and solutions